# How to nginx reverse proxy on locations other than /

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am trying to setup nginx as reverse proxy to multiple services, I deployed nginx as a docker container using the following copose file

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  nginx:
    image: 'nginx:stable'
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - nginx-net
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - nginx:/etc/nginx/

volumes:
  nginx:

networks:
  nginx-net:
    name: nginx-net
    driver: bridge
```

all my services run as docker containers connected to the docker network `nginx-net`, for testing I am using uptimeKuma (which will be one of the services I want to run) which is running using the folllowing compose file

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  kuma-dashboard:
    image: louislam/uptime-kuma:1
    container_name: kuma-dashboard
    volumes:
      - uptime-kuma:/app/data
    restart: always
    networks:
      - nginx-net

volumes:
  uptime-kuma:

networks:
  nginx-net:
    external: true
```

I tried setting the reverse proxy in the `conf.d/registry.conf` file in the `nginx` volume as follows

```
server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     SERVER_LOCAL_IP;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        location / {
                proxy_pass      http://kuma-dashboard:3001/;
        }
}
```

which worked well on `http://SERVER_LOCAL_IP/`, but when I try to forward to a different location

```
server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     SERVER_LOCAL_IP;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        location /test {
                proxy_pass      http://kuma-dashboard:3001/;
        }
}
```

`http://SERVER_LOCAL_IP/test` forwards me to a blank page.
I tried adding

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
proxy_set_header   Host $host;
```

to the `.conf` as suggested [here](https://github.com/louislam/uptime-kuma/wiki/Reverse-Proxy#nginx), with no effect to the result. What am I missing to forward requests to other locations than `/`

Comment: With this configuration, you will redirect to uptime-kuma routes and if there is no route named `test` it won't do anything. Try with `location /setup-database-info` for example witch exists. Thanks

Comment: same result, I also tried `/dashboard` and removing the `/` form `proxy_pass` to pass `dashboard` to the proxy link, still facing a blank page

Comment: try including the ports in the uptime-kume compose file: 
    ports:
      - 3001:3001

Comment: but that would render nginx useless, besides if they are on the same docker network, it should not matter weather or not the port is exposed.